# Difference between not and don't in the next sentence

Tags: american-english, negation, formal-language, do-support

> “In the period we not enter, Romanticism, the Account became the
>   preeminent formula for literary production.”

In the sentence above, does the ‘**not**’ make sense? Should I use ‘**don’t**’ instead?

Comment: I suspect that "not" is a typo for "now" or perhaps "next", but without the source, cannot confirm this.

Comment: Mantra, where is this from? Did you write it? What is the context?

Comment: I'm almost certain this is a typo for _now_, as suggested by @DavidSiegel. It's certainly not grammatical as it stands.

Comment: The sentence, even after books4languages correction, still doesn't make sense. What is the "Account" a story, a novel, a romance? And why do we *not* enter the Romanticism period?

Comment: Please, in the future, provide more context in your posts. Where did you find it? What's the context? etc. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a one-off error.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have 'not' + verb in this sentence. It is better to write:

> “In the period that we do not (don't) enter, Romanticism, the Account
>   became the preeminent formula for literary production.”

You can see more about this rule here: https://open.books4languages.com/english-a1-grammar/chapter/present-simple-negative/

Comment: Thank you. You see, that sentence was written by my literature professor. I thought something looked odd, and indeed, it is not properly written.